What does “simultaneous events” mean in probability? Does it refer to the possibility of events occurring together or at the same time?
If a coin is tossed twice, and we’re asked to determine the probability of getting Heads both times, we apply the multiplication rule and obtain 1/4. My question is, although the answer is clear and the concept of why we are multiplying is understood, these events happen sequentially, one after another. Why then do we say they are simultaneous when there’s elapsed time and we didn’t use two coins to observe Heads both times? Could we say we can use the multiplication rule for consecutive  events as well?  These are two questions. Thanks.

Consecutive independent events: the coin has no memory of its previous toss.

A good question, and it really comes down (in my opinion) to what you are wanting to calculate at the time.
Consider two coins (each with $Pr(H)=\frac{1}{2}$) flipped together or one flipped twice and $X$ be the discrete random variable that counts the number of Heads observed.
My the multiplication principle, or by the fact that the two coin flips are independent, $Pr(X=2)=\frac{1}{4}$.
So, why can we consider two coin flips happening together when we flip the one coin twice?
Because the trial (Bernoulli trial if you want to be specific) is the flipping of a coin, but we have defined the event as the total number of Heads observed being 0, 1 or 2.
Since we assign probabilities to events, the whole calculation makes sense.
